# I get the error "Only a type can be imported" in jsp/Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I'm trying to apply CRUD function in a Dynamic WEB App project in Eclipse IDE with tomcat v9.0. After giving inputs I get the error -

```
Type: Exception Report

Message: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

Description: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception:
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\work\Catalina\localhost\Testing4\org\apache\jsp\Controller\insert_005fcontroller_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. crud.Insert_Values resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [20] in the jsp file: [/Controller/insert_controller.jsp]
Insert_Values cannot be resolved to a type
17:     String user_name = request.getParameter("user_name");
18: 
19:     
20:     Insert_Values obj_Insert_Values = new Insert_Values();
21:     obj_Insert_Values.insert_values(sl_no, user_name, email, mobile);
22:     
23:     

An error occurred at line: [20] in the jsp file: [/Controller/insert_controller.jsp]
Insert_Values cannot be resolved to a type
17:     String user_name = request.getParameter("user_name");
18: 
19:     
20:     Insert_Values obj_Insert_Values = new Insert_Values();
21:     obj_Insert_Values.insert_values(sl_no, user_name, email, mobile);
22:     
23:
```

Here is my java class:

```
package crud;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import common.DB_Connection;

public class Insert_Values {

    public void insert_values(String sl_no, String user_name, String email, String mobile) {

        DB_Connection obj_DB_Connection = new DB_Connection();
        Connection connection = obj_DB_Connection.getConnection();

        PreparedStatement ps=null;

        String query = "insert into user(sl_no, user_name,email,mobile) values(?,?,?)";
        try {
            ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);

            ps.setString(1, sl_no);
            ps.setString(2, user_name);
            ps.setString(3, email);
            ps.setString(4, mobile);

            ps.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

There are my jsp files:

```
<%@ page import="crud.Insert_Values"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<%

    String sl_no = request.getParameter("sl_no");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String mobile = request.getParameter("mobile");
    String user_name = request.getParameter("user_name");


    Insert_Values obj_Insert_Values = new Insert_Values();
    obj_Insert_Values.insert_values(sl_no, user_name, email, mobile);


%>

Finished




</body>
</html>
```

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Insert Values</h1>

<form action = "Controller/insert_controller.jsp">

Sl No :<input type = "text" name = "sl_no"><br>
User Name :<input type = "text" name = "user_name"><br>
Mobile: <input type ="text" name = "mobile"><br>
Email: <input type = "text" name = "email"><br>

<input type = "submit" value = "Insert">



</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a `crud/Insert_Values` folder in your sources in addition to your `Insert_Values.java` file? Tomcat seems to think so.

Comment: Insert_Values.java file is inside the crud folder (crud package)

Comment: Have you made sure that there is not a `Insert_Values` folder?

Comment: @nitind Yes, there is no `Insert_Values` folder

Comment: The other possibility is that your class is somehow not being deployed. How are you launching Tomcat?

Comment: @nitind What do you mean by "launching Tomcat"? I launched it from Eclipse IDE as I think :(